# Problems when I save in form update using form complex yii2

Tags: php, forms, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have three tables namely family (PK id_family and FK id_husband), husband (PK id_husband) and house (PK id_husband). For the husband is related to the house. Then the husband of the table relate to the family table.

I've made an update form to form house to see the reference below. Prior to that logic when I update in form house, a field that is in the table will be to update husband, in the mean field namely 'status_husband'. For it has been successful in doing.
Then, when the process save in actionUpdate, to field at the family table will be loaded automatically when the input on the update form house. Fieldnya id_family, id_husband and status_family. For it has been managed well and I use the concept of form complex.

I want to when in the update and will make the process of it all, there is validation to require that all of the fields in the form update house which the 'province' and 'city' must be filled with value 'example1' all. So if one difference will not be processed. Maybe someone can help me, thanks

Code view in form update house..

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Modal;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Husband;
use kartik\widgets\Select2;

?>

<h1 align="center">Form Ubah House</h2>
<?php
echo "&nbsp";
echo "&nbsp";
?>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal', 
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'id' => 'update-form',
    ]); 
?>

<?php 
    $data = ArrayHelper::map(Husband::find()->all(), 'id_husband', 'name_husband'); 

    echo $form->field($house, 'id_husband')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $data,
    'model' => $house,
    'language' => 'id',
    'disabled' => true,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Choose..'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => false,
        'width' => '300px',
        ],
    ])->label('Name husband');
?>


<?php 
echo $form->field($house, 'province')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'model' => $house,
    'hideSearch' => true,
    'data' => ['example1' => "Example1", 'example2' => "Example2"],
    'language' => 'id',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Choose..',
        'id' => 'province',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => false,
        'width' => '380px',
        ],
    ])->label('Province'); 
?>  

<?php 
echo $form->field($house, 'city')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'model' => $house,
    'hideSearch' => true,
    'data' => ['example1' => "Example1", 'example2' => "Example2"],
    'language' => 'id',
    'disabled' => true,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Choose..',
        'id' => 'city',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => false,
        'width' => '380px',
        ],
    ])->label('City'); 
?>

<?= $form->field($family, 'id_family')->hiddenInput(['readOnly' => true, 'style' => 'width:100px'])->label(false); ?>

<?php
$family->id_husband = $house->id_husband;
?>
<?= $form->field($family, 'id_husband')->hiddenInput(['style' => 'width:100px'], ['disabled' => true])->label(false); ?>

<?= $form->field($family, 'status_house')->hiddenInput(['style' => 'width:380px', 'value'=>'Tetap'], ['disabled' => true])->label(false); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4">

<?= Html::submitButton('Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php
echo "&nbsp";
echo "&nbsp"; 
echo Html::a('Exit', ['index'],[
    'class'=>'btn btn-success',
    'onclick' =>'$("#houseModal").modal("hide");
    return false;'
    ]);
?>

<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

Code actionUpdate in HouseController

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $house = House::findOne($id);
        if (!$house) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The house was not found.");
        }

        $family = new Family();
        if (!$family) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("The family was not found.");
        }

        if ($house->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $family->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $isValid = $house->validate();
            $isValid = $family->validate() && $isValid;
            if ($isValid) {

                // Code for update field status_husband in table Husband
                $husband = Husband::findOne($id);
                $husband->status_husband = 'Meninggal';
                $husband->save();

                // Code for update field in table house
                $house->save(false);

                // Code for insert in table family
                $family->save(false);

                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Success!');
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
                return $this->refresh();
            }
        } else {
            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                return $this->renderAjax('update', [
                    'house' => $house,
                    'family' => $family]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('update', [
                    'house' => $house,
                    'family' => $family]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just to make sure if i actually understood what you want to do, you need to make sure the 3 models only get saved when all of them pass their respective validations?

Comment: I'm sure for each validations in models has pass @marche.

Answer (score 0):

If all 3 models are saving to the same Database using the same db connection component, you can use a database transaction:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $house = House::findOne($id);
    if (!$house) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The house was not found.");
    }

    $family = new Family();
    if (!$family) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The family was not found.");
    }

    $husband = Husband::findOne($id); // Why use the same $id that you use to find $house?
    if (!$husband) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("The husband was not found.");
    }

    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    // we get the database component used by the House model class and begin a transaction
    $transaction = House::getDb()->beginTransaction();

    try {
        if ($house->load($post) && $family->load($post)) {

            // Try to save $house model
            if(!$house->save()) {
                // If we get a validation error then we will throw an exception and execute the code in catch
                throw new \Exception('House Validation Error');
            }

            // Try to save $family model
            if(!$family->save()) {
                // If we get a validation error then we will throw an exception and execute the code in catch
                throw new \Exception('Family Validation Error');
            }

            // Set new status for $husband
            $husband->status_husband = 'Meninggal';

            // Try to save $husband model
            if(!$husband->save()) {
                // If we get a validation error then we will throw an exception and execute the code in catch
                throw new \Exception('Husband Validation Error');
            }

            // we commit the database changes after every model has been saved succesfully
            $transaction->commit();

            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Success!');
            return $this->redirect(['index']);

            // This doesn't get called ever, so why have it here?
            // return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Load Error');
        }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        // If we catch any exception we rollback the transaction, reverting all the changes made during the transaction
        $transaction->rollback();
    }

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('update', [
            'house' => $house,
            'family' => $family]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'house' => $house,
            'family' => $family]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic codes same with me. I want if data of family will be stored at table family when user input field province and city must 'example1'. If not then family data will not be stored in table family, but for table husband and house keep change. I try for give example : When I try input in form update house with value in field province is 'example1' and field city is 'example2'. So at table family will not be stored, but when I input each field province and city is 'example1' then data family will be stored. The problems is I don't know way for make it.